# How to play a video in twitter inline.

Tags: jquery

In my application the URL has consists of 170+ characters.By using share button i was shared my URL to Facebook and Twitter.In facebook it was working good(Video playing fine),but in twitter the videos couldnt play inline and also when i click the link,video plays in new tab.
please tell how to play a video in twitter inline and send me source code.

Comment: You can't. Twitter messages are text only. Images are parsed and linked to messages, videos are definetly not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL for your video is 170+ characters long?

I believe twitter only allows up to 140 characters, and the only way to display videos linked on twitter is if twitter supports that video URL type.

For example, YouTube videos play on Twitter, but only because twitter have put some code in place to recognise the YouTube URL, and play the video.

Comment: Thanks,Can you please tell me is it possible to share my 170+ URL to digg,delicious and linkedin.The above mentioned sites are also behaving like twitter.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible. Twitter does not support converting links into videos